# How to update Dart on VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgU3y.png)Today VS Code sent me an error:

> Version 2.16.1 of the Dart SDK is available (you have 2.16.0). Some features of Dart Code may not work correctly with an old SDK.

Do I have to download it again as ZIP and add it to PATH for the update?

Answer (score 6):

It should work with

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade from Extensions from VScode
[image]

Comment: There are no updates for the plugin, but in case of an update error, it left a link to the DART site.

Answer (score 0):

For linux try this,

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

or this

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also install the wanted version of [flutter SDK](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows?gclid=Cj0KCQiAkuP9BRCkARIsAKGLE8WH_O9HxPVlpJg0FTqOoxQj7-3c_f5EY43cHpuLFSPVLUCOZuq99TMaAl_LEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

This page introduces how to install and set the path in the system enviroment.

you could also downgrade the flutter version: flutter downgrade vxx.xx.xx